# can't seem to get composing functions right

Tags: function, ml

I'm having trouble composing functions in ML

```
local
    fun add(g:int->int,f:int->int,m:int,x:int,sum:int):int=
    if m>x then sum
           else add(g,g o f,m+1,x,sum+(g f x))             
in
    fun sum f g x=
    if x=0 then f x
           else add(g,g o f,1,x,f x)  
end;
```

now, what I'm trying to do is basically f(x)+g(f(x))+g(g(f(x)))+...+g^x(f(x))
but I can't get it right. I keep getting an error that operand and operator don't agree for g o f. can someone point out what I'm doing wrong and maybe how can I fix it?

```
fun sum f g x
```

is a given signature of a function so I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the error is in `g o f`, it's in `g f x`. That does not type-check, because `g` is not a function of two arguments. Did you mean `g(f x)` there, perhaps?